# Minimize freezing of brake cables

Tags: brakes, winter, ice

Is there something I can spray on my brake cables to keep them from freezing up in cold weather?

I want something preferably that will not attract dust.

Brakes froze when temperature was 20 degrees F.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you be more specific as to what type of brakes and cable you are using?

Comment: Is it the front or rear brake that freezes?  From the pictures I would guess the rear.

Comment: Do you store your bike inside/under cover or out in the rain?  Keeping it dry means there's nothing to freeze.  Fitting a mudguard/fender on the rear tyre and under the caliper will help a lot, as that will reduce the dirty water hitting the brake.

Comment: I don't recall which brakes froze. My bike is uncovered. I don't think cover would help as it's very humid where I live.

Comment: If you feel a need to inject a liquid, lock deicer would be the way to go.  This is generally an alcohol/glycol base with a touch of some sort of lubricant.

Comment: I would also recommend shortening the rear brake housing length so that is sits more tightly and in general does not have a "local minimum" point. The cable should monotonically go from the highest point at the shifter to the lowest point at the brake caliper being directed always down, not having even a short section that goes up. This will result in that any water that enters the cable has a chance of leaving it by the pure force of gravity.

Comment: I will make sure cable is always going downhill.

Comment: The stunt bikes with the spin-around fork that were popular maybe 10-15 years back were notorious for getting water in the front cable housing.  The cable ran down through the center of the headset bearing, then bent in a U upward to terminate at the brake.  So the cable housing end was pointing straight up.  Inevitably (OK, in at least 4 out of 5 cases) the cable would be rusted up and "frozen" (refusing to move at all).  When I get one of those to rehab I unhitch the brake end of the cable and force oxalic acid into the housing, to dissolve the rust, then push through some waxy chain lube.

Comment: If you can keep the water out, the cable can't freeze. The lube can still thicken in the cold though.  I'd suggest storing the bike inside overnight as a first solution.

Comment: One (moderately expensive) option would be upgrade the front disk to hydraulic.

Answer (score 6):

They are likely freezing because water is getting into the space between cable outer (cable housing) and the cable inner (the wire brake cable). Water expands as it freezes, in doing so it takes up more space than is available in an otherwise the restricted system.  Because the cable housing is relatively inflexible to expansion (it needs to be otherwise your brakes would be mushy) this ends up binding the inner brake cable causing your brakes to metaphorically and literally freeze.

About the only way to fix the freezing is to prevent water from getting into that space.  Adding oil or grease will likely not be enough to displace all the water, and as the remaining water expands when turning into ice you are left with the same problem.

As a quick fix you can bring your bike into someplace above freezing and hang it so that the water can drain out of the cable housing.

A more permanent fix depends on whether or not you can fully seal the system against water ingress. This depends on the type of brakes you have and how the brake cable is routed. I have only ever experienced freezing of brakes in sub-zero conditions on a bikes that were using full length brake housing, with the rear mechanical disc brake was mounted on the lower chain stay with no real seal between the brake housing and the disc caliper.  Rain water would slowly drip into the cable housing from the open end at the caliper and pool somewhere mid-chain stay.  Then when the weather dropped below freezing the rear brake would freeze solid.

The only to prevent this is to have some sort of seal that prevents water ingress into the housing from happening (e.g., see below)

[image: Mechanical brake caliper with sealing]

If you have another type of brake system or a different cable routing from what is pictured above I would need to see a picture to try and diagnose how water is entering and remaining in your brake housing.

### UPDATE

From your picture your cable boot on the rear brake appears to be dislodged. This will allow water to enter the system, where it will pool in the cable housing just after the brake noodle (see figure below).

[image: Diagram showing issue with OP rear brake]

Comment: Yes, my commute bike gets very dirty due to the combination of very wet winters and riding a lot of gravel and dirt paths to avoid traffic.  No, I will not clean it before the dry sunny weather returns.

Answer (score 0):

Wd40 might work and I'm sure you already have some so it might be worth a try

Comment: WD40 won't help here sorry.   Its possible a squirt of grease at the end of the outer could help to stop water entering, but OP needs to remove the water from inside the lowest point of their brake cable first.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and poured a pipet of antifreeze into the brake lines with great results.  I had to do the same with my bike lock which also froze.

Comment: Antifreeze is toxic to plants and the environment as well as to animals and humans. Much better to boot your cables and prevent further water ingress.